# Text/Image Phaser 3 render issue

Tags: javascript, image, png, phaser-framework

I am new to Phaser 3. I have an issue where when I run my game on a local host the text appears but the image does not. I have tried doing multiple things to get the image to load changing the folder routes, changing the folder in relation to the src folder, renaming the png, making sure the path is correct, making sure the tag is correct, trying other pngs. The dev tools show no errors in the browser. I am using parcel as my bundler not sure if that is the issue. Here are screenshots of my folder structure and what the browser looks like. Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

main.js

```
const Phaser= require('phaser');
const Game= require ("../src/scenes/Game")
  var config = {
    width: 800,
    height: 500,
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
   };
var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
game.scene.add("game", Game);
game.scene.start("game");`
```

---

Game.js

```
const Phaser = require("phaser");
class Game extends Phaser.Scene {
   preload() {
   this.load.image("wind", "../assets/Wind.png");
   }
   create() {
   const text = this.add.text(400, 250, "hello world");
   text.setOrigin(0.5, 0.5);
   this.add.image(400, 250, "wind");
   }
}

module.exports = Game;
```

---

index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
   <title>A Storm's a Brewin</title>
  </head>
<body>
  <script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>`
```

---

package.json

```
    {
  "name": "stormbrewer",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel src/index.html",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.5",
    "phaser": "^3.54.0"
  }
}
```

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H728j.png)

[What the browser looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fho7s.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write
`this.load.image("wind", "../assets/Wind.png")`, that path is relative to the position of the file that is loaded by the browser.

The browser loads the file (usually) from the `dist` folder, not directly from the `src`.

I think you can solve by changing assets folder and telling Parcel how to pack your assets so that `xxx/assets` will be in `dist/assets`.

I usually use [parcel-plugin-static-files-copy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parcel-plugin-static-files-copy), and create a `public` folder along with `src` and put this in `package.json`

```
...
"staticFiles": {
  "staticPath": "public"
},
...
```

Folder structure

```
package.json
public
| assets
| | any.png
src
| Game.js
```

Another solution could be to change how you reference the files that you "give" to Phaser (maybe with a `require(...)` or something). I know it's somehow possible but the first solution it's enough for my purposes so I didn't dig enough to explain it, but I think it's worth mention it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I did try it and still got the same result. Two follow up questions. Is there a specific place I should put the "static files" code in package.json in terms of after or before dependencies? Could you elaborate more on the require solution? Or point me in a direction to find more information?

Comment: package.json is not an ordered list, so you can put staticFiles anywhere.
But I found out that this solution comes with a plugin "parcel-plugin-static-files-copy" (i improve my answer, sorry).

Comment: About the `require` I think it would be something like `this.image.load('my-image', require('images/my-image.png'))`, I do not have any reference to give you.

Comment: I tried the parcel-plugin-static -files-copy and that did not work. I am not sure why. The require suggestion did, thank you so much! Do you know anything about parcel v2? Do I need to update the parcel in my package.json? If so, how?

Comment: The documentation (https://v2.parceljs.org/getting-started/webapp/) says to install v2 with `yarn add -D parcel@next` or `npm install -D parcel@next` but it's still in beta as far as I know.